# absolute continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If I know that a function $f:R\to R$ is absolute continuous then I know that is has derivative a.e my question is if I look in the limit :

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \ n \cdot \left(f(x)-f\left(x-\frac{1}{n}\right)\right)$$
is there  possibility that this limit does not exist in some point?

thnak you

Comment: the limit is equal $f'(x)$ a.e. See [Lebesgue's differentiation theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem)

Comment: so there might be cases that for countable set  of x's this limit is not even exist?

Comment: Make an example along the lines of $x\cos(\pi/x)$

Comment: thank you for your answers - however I don't see why The example given  is absolute continuous  function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $x=0$, and the function $f(x) = \int_x^0 g(t)\; dt$ where $g(t) = +1$ on the intervals $(-3^{-2k+1}, -3^{-2k})$ and $-1$ on the intervals $(-3^{-2k}, -3^{-2k-1})$ for positive integers $k$.